# Powershell script run against share on server

Tags: powershell, delete-file, recycle-bin

I'm running a powershell script that's on my local PC on a file share that's on a server.  I had code in the script to let the user select to delete something permanently (using Remove-Item) or to send something to the Recycle bin using this code:

```
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.Filesystem]::DeleteFile($file.fullname,'OnlyErrorDialogs','SendToRecycleBin')
```

When run locally (either from my desktop, or from the server) against a folder that's local to that respective location, it works fine.  A file that is identified gets deleted & immediately shows up in the recycle bin.

However, if run from my desktop to the file share, it deletes the file, but it doesn't show up in either the server's recycle bin or the local one either. I've tried UNC naming and mapped drive naming, and have come to believe this may be by design.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Only files deleted from redirected folders end up in the recycle bin. If you want to be able to undelete files deleted across the network then you need to use a third-party utility.

Comment: That's the answer that I was afraid would be the solution.